# Gradle buildscript dependency not found

Tags: gradle, dependencies

Note, that this question may be partially answered by solving the specific problem, but solving the general problem is also appreciated.

## Specific problem

I need to pass command-line options to Gradle code.  Gradle doesn't have any sensible way to do it, so I need to extract them somehow from `System` properties and later to parse them.  I was trying to employ `org.apache.common.cli` package for this.  But I cannot import it into the build code.

This is roughly what it looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { ... }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: "commons-cli", name: "commons-cli", version: "1.2"
    }
}
...
org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser
```

And I'm getting this:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'somewhere/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'somewhere/build.gradle': 35: unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser
   @ line 35, column 1.
     import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser
```

I have no idea what went wrong or how to debug this.  I've also tried Groovy's `groovy.util.CliBuilder`, but this breaks with even more arcane errors.

So, to solve my immediate problem: I'd be happy to find a simple way to parse command-line arguments passed to Gradle's build.

## Generic problem

Is there any way to debug Gradle code? By debugging I don't mean appending `--debug` argument to it's command line options.  It just prints a ton of irrelevant nonsense, but tells you nothing about what it was trying to do and what went wrong.  I mean something like an actual debugger.

Is there a way to know what dependencies it was trying to load, and did it succeed at loading them, and if so, where did it load them from?

Is there any way to translate the "Gradle language" into something that can be analyzed by a linter / editor s.t. one would know what parts of it do / if it makes sense to add other parts of certain kind (what I mean is some sort of intellisense to make understanding problems like unmet dependencies easier)?

Comment: What do you mean there is no sensible way to pass command line parameters? Did you try using the `-P` option? See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties

Comment: @RaGe (a) This is lame compared to any library that does command-line parsing (you want to be able to add a description to a command-line option, to have options groups, to automatically generate errors if arguments don't match your format etc.) (b) This is not usable on a basic level (this errors if you don't define a corresponding project property, this isn't accessible to your classes in definition scope).

Comment: Do you mean the type of help you get when you run `gradle tasks`? Just to rule out that this isn't a case of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), could you maybe describe what it is that you're trying to do through parsing command line arguments?

Answer (score 1):

This post is asking several questions and is highly subjective (re: "doesn't have any sensible way"). I'll do what I can.

First, as a sanity check for buildscript, let's try Apache Commons Lang3:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'
    }
}

println "TRACER : " + StringUtils.class.simpleName
```

The above script works, but with Gradle 2.14.1, I can confirm that `DefaultParser` from Apache Commons CLI 1.3.1 (as an aside, it's not in [v 1.2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-1.2/)) does not work. I suspect this is related to [this bug](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1981). The link mentions `dom4j` but it may be that `cli` is in the same category.

Regarding command-line arguments, the Gradle documentation contains examples of using `-P`, `-D`, `gradle.properties`, and so on. If you have a specific parsing issue, please create a new question with specifics.

Regarding dependencies, the following commands may be of use:

```
gradle dependencies
gradle buildEnvironment
```

see [this post](https://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2016/06/07/gradle-tricks-display-buildscript-dependencies/) for the latter.

Comment: Fortunately, I won't know if this works or not. But for posterity and those who will encounter this problem in the future: how do you know what are the valid words to write in "dependencies" block? How did you know it's "org.apapche.commons" and not "apache-commons" or any other variation? What do all these things mean? Manual has nothing to say about this, it only gives random examples, which differ greatly depending on the month they are published in and perhaps other factors that's not on the surface.

Comment: The Gradle doc covers this, though it may assume a familiarity with Maven co-ordinates. You are unfairly blaming Gradle for your own lack of experience with the JVM. The dependency spec for Apache Commons Lang3 came from this link (see Gradle tab) - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is truly unclear.